# jquery script that works when loaded "onload" but not "no wrap - in <head>" How can I fix this?

Tags: jquery, mediawiki

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeMaker/5GpuH/1/) for this project.  When the fiddle is set to "onLoad" it removes the element as it should.  However, when I flip the drop-down to "no wrap - in " it doesn't work.  I need it to work "no wrap - in " because I am using it on wikipedia and that is how they load their scripts.
My code is:

```
$('span.mw-usertoollinks a:last').remove();
$('span.mw-usertoollinks').each(function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(" | )", ")");
});
```

It is suppose to remove the block link and preceding `|` from:

```
<span class="mw-usertoollinks">
    (
    <a href="/UT:T13" class="mw-redirect" title="UT:T13">Talk</a>
     | 
    <a href="/S:Contributions/T13" title="S:Contributions/T13">contributions</a>
     | 
    <a href="/S:Block/T13" title="S:Block/T13">block</a>
    )
</span>
```

NOTE: I've abbreviated User_talk: to UT: and Special: to S: to make it fit better in the code box.  Everything else is original.

Comment: You need to wait until the elements exist before you try to select them. Common methods for that are to wait until the window is loaded, or to use $(document).ready()

Comment: See [modified html](http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeMaker/5GpuH/6/).  How do I make it work to remove ALL the block links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working outside the `onload` because the DOM elements you are trying to select don't exist when the code runs. Luckily, you can just wrap your code like this in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

And it will run only *after* the DOM has loaded.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GpuH/4/)

Note that `$(function(){...});` is a short hand for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. What you are doing is attaching code to be run only once the document.ready event is fired (i.e. after the DOM is fully loaded).

**Update**

Technically, this is another question, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5GpuH/7/) should work for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('span.mw-usertoollinks').each(function () {
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.children('a:last').replaceWith("-");
        $elem.html($elem.html().replace(" | -", ""));
    });
 });
```

Note when you use `$.each`, even with a jQuery selector, you are iterating over a collection of DOM nodes, not jQuery objects. So `this` needs to be converted into a jQuery object like this: `$(this)` in order to use jQuery functions on it. I'm caching the resulting jQuery object as `$elem` in order to avoid having to keep recreating it.

We use `children` to select the child nodes with the selector `a:last` to select only the last `a` link. Then we use `.html()` to manipulate the content of the `$elem` and remove the trailing characters.

Comment: It worked based on my original question... Except that it only does the last a of the last span... See [modified html](http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeMaker/5GpuH/6/).  How do I make it work to remove ALL the block links?

Comment: Thank you... Perfect... :)  Selected as top answer. :)